# \enumerate in \blockquote produces "missing \item" error when specified package options for csquotes

Tags: enumerate, csquotes

I am using XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[thresholdtype=words]{csquotes}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

    \blockquote{
        \textbf{konungr} (-s, -ar), \textit{m.}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item king.
        \end{enumerate}
    }

\end{document}
```

which produces the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.13 ^^I}
```

However, if I remove the package option for `csquotes`, i.e. replace line 3:

```
\usepackage[thresholdtype=words]{csquotes}
```

with this:

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
```

It compiles fine. The result looks like:

[image: the result]

which is properly indented.

This is a minimally compiling example. I do not want to remove that package option because I want to have a similarly indented `\blockquote` for a very short line that follows this. Without the package option, this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

    \blockquote{
        \textbf{konungr} (-s, -ar), \textit{m.}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item king.
        \end{enumerate}
    }

    \blockquote{
        Nouns like ``konungr'' \textit{king} and ``dvergr'' \textit{ghost} decline in the easiest pattern.
    }

\end{document}
```

the result is:

[image]

The second `\blockquote` does not get indented like the first one, but instead gets enclosed by double quotes.

Comment: Interesting problem. But does `\blockquote` even make sense? If you have an enumerated list, won't it always be a proper block quote? I'd think the `\begin{displayquote}` (in `csquote` language) or `\begin{quote}` environment would be the natural choice.

Comment: @jon Thank you. I replaced `\blockquote` with `\begin{displayquote}` and now it works regardless of whether the package option is specified or not. But I would still like to know why the errors occur in my situation explained in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the problem is due to how `csquotes` counts words, but I'm in no position to explain the gory details. However, you can work around the problem.

My first thought is that quotations which include lists should simply be put in `csquotes`' `displayquote` environment. That is,

```
\begin{displayquote}
  \textbf{konungr} (-s, -ar), \textit{m.}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item king.
    \end{itemize}
\end{displayquote}
```

Alternatively, you could create your own version of `\blockquote`, which switches from counting by words back to the default line-counting. The example below is merely proof of concept and provides a far 'dumber' `\blockquote`-type command than the original. (But maybe that's no real loss: I hever bother with the optional arguments myself.)

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[thresholdtype=words]{csquotes}
\SetBlockThreshold{50}
%\usepackage{enumitem}% this package does not affect problem

\newcommand\zzz[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setkeys{csq}{thresholdtype=lines}%
  \blockquote{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\example}{This is a minimally compiling example. I do not
  want to remove that package option because I want to have a
  similarly indented blockquote for a very short line that follows
  this.  This is a minimally compiling example. I do not want to
  remove that package option because I want to have a similarly
  indented blockquote for a very short line that follows this.}

\begin{document}

\example

\blockquote{This is a minimally compiling example.}

\blockquote{\example}

    \zzz{%
        \textbf{konungr} (-s, -ar), \textit{m.}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item king.
            \item or: ``rex''
        \end{itemize}
    }

\blockquote{\example}

\example

\blockquote{This is a minimally compiling example.}

\end{document}
```